How use Hall's theorem here?
The following question is derived from the first step of Claim 2 in the paper arxiv:2409.17724. The authors claimed that it follows from Hall's theorem. I can attempt a clumsy analysis, but is there truly a direct proof, as the authors suggests?
Question 1: Let $G$ be  a $4$-connected graph with $n\ge 8$ vertices. Let $u$ be a vertex of degree 4. Let $N_G(u)=\{a,b,c,d\}$. If all vertices $a,b,c$ are of degree $4$ in $G$. Prove that: $a,b,c$ have distinct neighbors   outside of $N_G[u]$.
Here, $N_G(u)$ denotes the set consisting of all its neighbors in a graph $G$, and $N_G[u]$ denotes the set consisting of the vertex $u$ and all its neighbors in a graph $G$.

$\textbf{Claim 2.}$ If $u$ is a vertex of $G$ of degree 4, then at most two neighbors of $u$ have degree 4.

Proof of Claim 2. Suppose, for a contradiction, that a vertex $u$ of degree $4$ has three neighbors $a$, $b$, and $c$ of degree $4$. Let $d$ be the fourth neighbor of $u$. Since $G$ is $4$-connected and $n \geq 8$, Hall’s theorem implies that the vertices $a$, $b$, and $c$ have distinct neighbors $a'$, $b'$, and $c'$, respectively, outside of $N_G[u]$....(omitted)...


We verify Hall's condition for the sets $X=\{a, b, c\}$ and $Y = V(G)\backslash N[u]$.
For $S\subset X$ with $|S|=1$, without loss of generality, we want to show that $a$ has a neighbour in $Y$. Suppose not, then $N(a) = N[u]\backslash \{a\}$, and thus $b, c, d$ form a $3$-vertex cut. Note that we are using the existence of other vertices in the graph, which follows from $n\geq 8$. The other two cases are similar.
Suppose $|S| = 2$, but $N(S)\cap Y\leq 1$. By the previous case, we may assume $N(S)\cap Y=1$, say $N(S)=\{y\}$. Then $\{a, b, c, d, y\}\backslash S $ is a $3$-vertex cut separating $u$ from the other vertices, of which there are at least two.
Suppose $S=X$, but $N(S)\cap Y\leq 2$. By the previous case, we may assume $N(S)\cap Y=2$, say $N(S)=\{y, z\}$. Then $\{d, y, z\}$ is a $3$-vertex cut separating $u$ from the other vertices, of which there is at least one.
Hence, Hall's condition holds, i.e., there is a perfect matching between $X$ and $Y$. In other words, $a,b,c$ have distinct neighbors outside of $N[u]$
